Number data type in Apache HOP
Apache HOP does not force you to set length and precision and format attributes. But then it outputs .csv file in format #,##0.0, that is rounds up to one decimal digit.
Do they guarantee this behaviour?
to reproduce:

add data Set Meta Data
add field f1 type number
on Data tab add value 3.14 and save
.
re-open the settings and verify the value is 3.1

pictures:
creating...

re-openning...


https://github.com/apache/hop/issues/3970 is filed after discussion with the team. this might be improved some time
